# Range-for-loops and the syntax

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, vector

I'm working my way through Stroustrup's C++ Programming Principles book and I've got to the part about range-for-loops The code given here is the direct example given, but I'm hoping someone can shed some light on what is actually going on with the loop.

```
int main()
{
    vector<double> temps; // temperatures
    for (double temp; cin>>temp; ) // read into temp
        temps.push_back(temp); // put temp into vector    

    // compute mean temperature:
    double sum = 0;
    for (int x : temps) 
        sum += x;
    cout << "Average temperature: " << sum/temps.size() << '\n';

    // compute median temperature:
    sort(temps); // sort temperatures
    cout << "Median temperature: " << temps[temps.size()/2] << '\n';

}
```

In particular, could someone please explain where `int x` comes from in the averaging loop. I am assuming the for loop in this scenario searches through the vector `temps`, but where does `int x` come into it?

Comment: It should be double; That must be an error which could possibly lead to truncation. The variable is just supposed to iterate over the vector.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Answer (score 4):

Generally, a range-for loop `for (declaration : range)` is equivalent to something like

```
for (auto it = begin(range); it != end(range); ++it)
{ 
    declaration = *it;
    // do something
}
```

(the code is simplified, there is actually [more to it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for))

So, if you declare a loop variable as `int x`, and iterate over a `vector<double>`, everything works except that you get a type cast `double -> int`:

```
int x = *it; // 'it' references a 'double'
```

With all that said, this seems to be a typo in the book. You'd want `for (double x : temps)` to calculate everything correctly.

Answer (score 1):

`for(int x: temps)` means for each element in the vector `temps`, let's name it `x`, and do something with `x`.

Answer (score 1):

You can read `for(int x: temps` as "for each element `x` in `temps`. In other words, the value of `x` is assigned from an element of `temps` one at a time as the loop iterates over the `vector`.

Note also that `int x` should be `double x` since the elements of `temps` are `double`s.

Answer (score 0):

In a [range-based loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) the `int x` is a *range declaration* and `temps` is a *range expression* (represented by a container / vector in this case). It means the variable `x` will take each of the values stored in `temps` vector one loop at the time. Also `x` should be of type `double` instead of `int` as `temps` is a vector of doubles:

```
for (double x : temps) {
        sum += x;
}
```

Or use an `auto` specifier and let the compiler deduce the appropriate type for `x`:

```
for (auto x : temps) {
        sum += x;
}
```

If you intend to modify the value of `x` inside the loop use the reference type:

```
for (auto& x : temps) {
        sum += x;
}
```

---

As for the first [for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for) the `double temp;` is the *init statement* and `cin >> temp;` is a *condition*. The loop will continue executing the `temps.push_back(temp);` statement until the condition becomes `false` when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> on your keyboard.

<sup>Please note that this way of using the for loop can be somewhat confusing.</sup>